# Change in wording of "on hold"

Tags: discussion

There is currently a discussion over on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261144/change-the-wording-of-on-hold-to-something-else) about whether the wording [on hold] should be changed when users vote to close a question.

It seems that we attract an unusually large number of questions that go on hold precisely because the original poster needs to edit their question to be clearer, more concrete, to show more individual effort, etc. In other words, we get a lot of on hold questions that could be reopened if the questions were improved a little.

My sense is therefore that we would benefit from a rewording to something like [needs improvement] or [needs edits] that more clearly conveys that being on hold really means "Hey, OP, please edit your question so we can write you a helpful answer." That would be clearer; would be more welcoming to new users; and would avoid having a long tail of closed, abandoned questions.

Whether you agree or not, do check out [Change the wording of "on hold" to something else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261144/change-the-wording-of-on-hold-to-something-else) and vote with your conscience.